# Delayed job is not sending email for specific email settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using `delayed_job_active_record` for pushing long running process to background. It works great except for email sending. It processes job and complete it but email never comes here. This problem is only on production.So, i tried switching the mailer setting back-and-forth and it turns out to be that if i use development setting it will work well but if i use production setting it doesn't.

I have tested the mailer setting without `delayed_job`, it works good in both environment so i am sure that the problem is not with email-settings.

In production environment

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.xyz.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =  {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'xyz',
  :password       => 'password123',
  :domain         => 'heroku.com'
}
```

In development enviornment

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting `RAILS_ENV` when you start your workers?

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs